# Discord py bot not going online in server

Tags: discord.py

My discord bot get this error this will explan what error I got from the message
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvpxG.png)

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")
    print(client.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send(message.content[::-1])

my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Please avoid presenting errors via attached images. Instead, please insert error messages as code blocks in your question.

Comment: Maybe you are working with an old tutorial? Check out the documentations. As the error states an intents object must be passed to client. See here for example [Discord API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord bots now require you to pass it a set of intents to run. Intents allow bot developers to "subscribe" to specific events in Discord.

Your discord client constructor takes a parameter of `intents`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents

You can construct your own object with custom intents, or just use an intents class method to give it all, default or no intents.